# PUA/Teoma.jzvgf by Avira quarantined; to be deleted or not? [Solved]

Tags: windows-10, avira

I use Avira on Windows 10 and since the Windows 10 1803 update (circa May 15th for me), Avira sometimes says to me that it has found a file named PUA/Teoma.jzvgf and quarantined it. And two or three boots of the computer later, Avira finds the same file et quarantines it again.
Furthermore, when I try to turn my computer off after the next boot, it does not turn off and it only logs me off, then logs in. I have to reboot the computer, so that I now can turn it off.
A short example:

- 1st boot: nothing happens, I can turn the computer off;
- 2nd boot: Avira finds Teoma.jzvgf and quarantines it, I can turn the computer off;
- 3rd boot: as I want to turn off the computer, it logs me off then in (no matter how many time I try to turn it off), I have to reboot the computer, then I can turn it off;
- 4th boot: nothing happens (sometimes Teoma.jzvgf is already found again), I can turn the computer off without problem.

It is not a big problem, stopping me using my computer, but it begins to be quite a nuisance. So should I delete the file PUA/Teoma.jzgvf when Avira finds and quarantines it? And how? using the “delete” button (I use the french version, so maybe “delete” is not the used verb in english, but you understood me) in the list of quarantined files? Or what other thing should I do?

I repeat that it happened for the first time shortly after the lastest Windows 10 update (the 1803). Therefore I think that it could be related.

I try to search some answsers with Google, but… I only found a few pages on the German speaking Avira web site: users seem to have Avira finding Teoma.jzvgf, but do not talk about not turning off computers. And I did not found clear answers (I spoke German, but I now am a little bit rusted): some, but not all, advised to delete the file, but nobody answers that it worked; so I prefer to ask myself the question (here and on the Avira website, but without answer there until now), where maybe more people will answer (and I added the concommitant problem of loging off/in instead of turning off).

Thanks for having read and for any help!

PS: I tried and tried again and again to edit my post and add a “Hello all!” at the beginning but it does not appear… sorry to seem rude by not saluting.

---

Edition (6/25): For more details, I noticed that the file is by Avira found and quarantined every 24 h; if the computer is off 24 h after the last quarantine, it waits until the next boot. I do not know if this information could be useful; does Avira release the file after 24 h? does it come back by its own?
 (Maybe should I try to disconnect my computer from Internet to see if the file is again found.)

Does someone have any answer, or at least idea, for me?

---

Edition (7/4): For some by me unknown reason, Avira did not find PUA/Teoma.jzvgf again since ten days. I waited some days just to be sure that it was not a short period without it before it resumes, but it seems not to appear again.
 I did not do anything to fix it: nor delete anything nor try some on the Internet found answer…

So the problem is solved, but I have nothing to say to other people to help with that.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We appreciate your trying to be polite, but we tend to consider "Hello" and "Thanks" to be noise because they don't add any information to the post. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).